# locking and passing parameter to a multi-threading code

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

i want to use a multi-threading program as follows, but when i run the program, R1,R2 and R3 are not the same.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParallelFor
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Program started");
           double R1 = 0.0;
           double R2 = 0.0;
           double R3 = 0.0;
           var t1 = new Thread(() => TestCounter(1000, ref R1, 1));
           var t2 = new Thread(() => TestCounter(1000, ref R2, 2));
           var t3 = new Thread(() => TestCounter(1000, ref R3, 3));
           t1.Start();
           t2.Start();
           t3.Start();

           do
           {
               Thread.Sleep(1000);
               Console.WriteLine("waiting...");
           } while (t1.IsAlive == true && t2.IsAlive == true &&   t3.IsAlive == true);

           Console.WriteLine("inside R1: {0}", R1);
           Console.WriteLine("inside R2: {0}", R2);
           Console.WriteLine("inside R3: {0}", R3);
           Console.WriteLine("Program finished");
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
       static void TestCounter(int counter, ref double result, int No)
       {
               for (int i = 0; i < counter + 1; i++)
                  for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
                      for (int k = 0; k < counter; k++)
                          result += (double)i;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not simplify and have one for loop? Also, what values do you get it they're not the same? One last thing - you don't need to have `== true` for bool values.

Comment: @Mahdy should you not wait for the threads to join?

Comment: You don't need to join the threads, if you're checking that they are alive.

Comment: I've voted to close your question as it's basically a misunderstanding of Boolean logic.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Joining would be *preferable* to a busywait.  It should be done instead.

Comment: @Servy would one just do `t1.Join(); t2.Join(); t3.Join();` instead?

Comment: @WaiHaLee I would re-design the whole application differently from top to bottom, but yes, that would be a step in the right direction over doing a busywait.

Answer (score 2):

Your `do` loop finishes as soon as the first thread is ready.

I think you want

```
while ( t1.IsAlive || t2.IsAlive || t3.IsAlive );
```

which will keep the`do` loop looping until all tests are ready.